# Use of Self-Signed Certificate under Named Credential

Tags: community, certificates, namedcredentials

Did anyone tried to use Self-Signed Certificate or any other type of certificate with Named Credentials.

I am trying to setup Named Credential under destination Salesforce org which will connect with Source Salesforce org. I have setup connected App in source org and used same Self-Signed Certificate at both places for authentication. But I got below error 
`"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"`

Help much Appreciated!